# Is it possible to set a http proxy & port on a iOS personal hotspot connection

Tags: iphone, network, wifi, proxy

When an iPhone is connected to a Wifi network, there is an option to set a manual http proxy and port.

When user has created an personal WIFI hotspot ( sharing the cellular connection) there is no user setting where I can setup a manual http proxy/port for the WIFI hotspots connection, or ( at least for my cellular data network ) for setting the http proxy/port of the cellular connection.    I want http from devices connected to the hotspot to be routed to an http proxy/port.

Is there a way , perhaps by installing a profile, that I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that iPhone hotspot blocks access between devices on the local network.
I've set up an HTTP proxy on my Windows device. My other Android phone can pass through the proxy tunnel when they're connected to the same rooter.
However, it won't work if they're connected to an iPhone hotspot.

My daily proxy app Shadowrocket works in the same way: It allows my iPhone to share the proxy to other devices when connected to the same network, which here means a rooter, NOT an iPhone hotspot.